# Beginners code: HTML Styling ID within ID not working

Tags: html, css, class

I have just started learning HTML and I am having problems with IDs/classes within IDs/classes.

So, to my knowledge, an ID is specified by a #. That would mean that if I wanted to style an ID within and ID, wouldn't that be:

```
#ID1 #ID2 {
    ...
}
```

Which would mean that the styling will only apply for ID2 that is inside ID1? Please correct me if I'm wrong. When I used the same principle within my (very simple beginner) code, it didn't work. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>1 May 2016</title>
    <style>
       #name {
           color: blue;
           font-family: Tahoma;
       }

       #parafont #1 {
           font-family: Arial;
       }

       #parafont #2 {
           font-family: Times;
       }

       #parafont #3 {
           font-family: Courier;
       }

       parafont #4 {
           font-family: Lucida Grande;
       }

       #parafont #5 {
           font-family: Helvetica;
       }

       #test1 #6 {
           color: blue;
       }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h3 id="name">Bob Bobbington</h3>
    <p>1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10</p>
    <p>When was this website created? Check the <b>title</b>.</p>
    <h3>All animals are quite interesting...</h3>
    <p id="parafont">
        <span id="1">This is a test paragraph.</span>
        <span id="2">Each sentence should have a different font.</span>
        <span id="3">This paragraph is going to use some styling.</span>
        <span id="4">Styling will change the font of each sentence.</span>
        <span id="5">Let's see whether it works!</span>
    </p>
    <div id="test1">
        <p id="6">Test</p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**All help is very much appreciated!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the id numbers `1` to something that starts with letters.

> `ID` and `NAME` tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Where did you quote that from? It would be great if someone could give a website defining all the tags.

Answer (score 0):

IDs can not start with numbers first of all. Also since IDs are meant to be specific, using nesting to select an element is redundant. #id #id2 would be the same thing as just #id2 as long as the more specific #id #id2 was used

Comment: That's not quite true. If there was a selector that had `#id2` it would be overridden by a more specific selector like `#id1 #id2`.